# Given two distinct points in a topology, can you always find a basis element which only intersects one of them?

Tags: general-topology

In Example 2 of Section 30 in "Topology" (James R. Munkres, 2nd Ed), the book states:

> In the uniform topology, $\mathbb R^\omega$ satisfies the first countability axiom (being metrizable). However, it does not satisfy the second. To verify this fact, we must first show that if $X$ is a space having a countable basis $\mathcal{B}$, then any discrete subspace $A$ of $X$ must be countable. Choose, for each $a\in A$, a basis element $B_a$ that intersects $A$ at the point $a$ alone. If $a$ and $b$ are distinct points of $A$, the sets $B_a$ and $B_b$ are different, since the first contains $a$ and the second does not. It follows that the map $a\to B_a$ is an injection of $A$ into $\mathcal{B}$, so $A$ must be countable.

I'm confused about why it's possible to do this:

> Choose, for each $a\in A$, a basis element $B_a$ that intersects $A$ at the point $a$ alone.

Given an arbitrary set $A$ containing points $a$ and $b$ in a topological space $X$ with basis $\mathcal{B}$, can we really always find basis elements $B_a, B_b\in\mathcal{B}$ intersecting $A$ which contain only $a$ and $b$ respectively? It seems like an extra assumption about $X$ as well as the basis $\mathcal{B}$, similar to the Hausdorff property.

Comment: $A$ is not arbitrary here, it is assumed to be discrete. In particular, the set $\{a\}$ is open in $A$, so it equals $A\cap U$ for some open $U\subseteq X$. Now take $B$ to be a basis element which satisfies $a\in B\subseteq U$. Then such $B$ intersects $A$ only at the point $a$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space

Comment: @WillJagy $X$ isn't necessarily a $T_1$ space though. The book just states "If $X$ is a space having countable basis, then any discrete subspace of $X$ must be countable".

Comment: @Mark Why is the set $\{a\}$ necessarily open in $A$? The open sets of $A$ are defined to be the sets $U\cup A$ where $U$ is an open set in $X$. It's not clear to me why there must exist an open set $U\subset X$ such that $U\cup A=\{a\}$. I don't see how $A$ being discrete guarantees that fact, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @SiddharthaHarmalkar First of all, it should be $U\cap A$, not $U\cup A$. Second, the definition of a discrete space is a topological space where all the subsets are open. (i.e the topology is just the collection of all subsets) Here it was assumed that the subspace topology of $A$ equals the discrete topology on $A$. This is the meaning of $A$ being a "discrete subspace".

Comment: @Mark Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: @Mark your comment looks like an answer